# How to read function description in code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reflection, documentation, jsdoc

I have this code

```
/** This is test function
 * @param  {} param1 this is param 1
 * @param  {} param2 this is param 2
 */
function test(param1, param2) {

}
```

And I am looking for a way to get this js doc description in **code**. 
For instance

```
function getMethodJsDocData(){
  // The magic happens here and returns some data that contains:
  /** This is test function
   * @param  {} param1 this is param 1
   * @param  {} param2 this is param 2
   */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this will be possible.

Closure Compiler is not JS compiling JS, its an independent Java program that compiles JS.

JS itself is unaware of `/* comments*/` in general